# maskMoney(jquery) não exibindo valor de forma correta

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

Boa Tarde pessoal, estou com um problema ao usar o plugin maskMoney do jQuery.
Estou usando a seguinte declaração antes

```html
<div style="float:left; width: 25%">
  <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="Valor Total: "></asp:Label>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvValTotalEnsinoSuperior"        runat="server" ErrorMessage="Valor Total: Campo obrigatório."            ControlToValidate="tbValorTotalEnsinoSuperior" Display="Dynamic"  Text="*" ValidationGroup="ParteReembolsoEnsinoSuperior" ForeColor="Red"  SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="tbValorTotalEnsinoSuperior" Size="25%" runat="server" MaxLength="100" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
  <br /><br />
</div>
```

```js
$("[id*=tbValorTotalEnsinoSuperior]").maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$ ', thousands: '.', decimal: ',' });

E em minha função tenho:   
    $("[id*=tbValorTotalEnsinoSuperior]").maskMoney('mask',0.01);
```

Mas na TextBox ele coloca o valor como R$1,00 em vez de R$0,01

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Seu código parece funcionar normalmente. Pode ser outra coisa influenciando.

Comment: Tente colocando o valor entre aspas com vírgula: `$("[id*=tbValorTotalEnsinoSuperior]").val("0,01");`

Comment: Tenta mudar a cultura da sua aplicação, talvez esteja usando a cultura diferente do pt-BR.

Comment: O mais estranho é que se na mascara eu trocar a ordem do '.'(ponto) e da ','(virgula) ele exibe o valor correto R$0.01 mas com a virgula na frente ele continua exibindo R$1,00

Answer (score 1):

Tenta trocar o método `.val()` por método `.maskMoney('mask', 0.01);`

Exemplo:

```
$("[id*=tbValorTotalEnsinoSuperior]").maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$ ', thousands: '.', decimal: ',' });
$("[id*=tbValorTotalEnsinoSuperior]").maskMoney('mask', 0.01);
```

Veja o resultado:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#currency").maskMoney({
    prefix: 'R$ ',
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ','
  }).maskMoney('mask', 0.01);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="currency" />
```

**Update:**

Seu código funciona perfeitamente com método `.val();`, veja o resultado:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#currency").maskMoney({
    prefix: 'R$ ',
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ','
  });

  $("#currency").val(0.01);

  $("#currency").maskMoney('mask');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="currency" />
```

Comment: Vlw pela resposta, mas msm com essas alterações a textbox continua exibindo o valor R$ 1,00 em vez de R$ 0,01

Comment: @PhilipeMatheus Coloca o seu código html na sua pergunta.

Comment: pronto, coloquei o html

Comment: @PhilipeMatheus Está usando ASP.NET Web Forms ?

Comment: não, n é web forms